# flutter SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

I am using flutter and my android studio is located in E:\android studio and getting this issue"SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
" whenever tried to run

Answer (score 0):

download git restart your system and add your flutter SDK path in your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I'am stack with same issue. And this solution helped me

Firstly check this one
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows - this guide for flutter installation (very easy to follow it, step by step)

Second check that you complete all this steps:

1. First you need download SDK from the link above.
2. Init Flutter with Path: For it open computer -> right click -> select properties -> advanced system settings (left side) -> tab advanced -> Environment variables. -> On user variables click on Path -> Then click 'New' on right side and put link to bin folder in flutter (something like this D:\8.Program\flutter\bin)

If you did all correct open cmd and write flutter. if you received flutter not recognized you did something wrong. If you received some text all good, lets continue.

Now you can open cmd command and write:
flutter create "NameOfApp"- it will create folder, that you can open from android studio like java or kotlin project.

Remember if you called cmd from default folder it will create project there. So you can change directory in cmd or just crtl+x, ctrl+v.